# Can you use an ID or class of a HTML element as an identifier for CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm on my road trip roundabout of learning more coding languages. Never practiced HTML since HTML 4.01. But this is more of a CSS thing.

I was expecting, since I see H1 and P1 being a thing, so I try button1. Feel stupid, then think about using an ID as an identifier. I want to make one button on the left and the other on the right side.

I can't find anything on w3schools, and other sites. I feel like I'm wording everything wrong.

Comment: Yes you can, In your stylesheet, If you want to reference said element, you can use `#{id-of-element}`. If you have set something like `<h1 id='id-of-element'>......`. If you used a class instead, you can use a dot (.) to identify it; eg: `.{name-of-class}`

Comment: Each tag in HTML has its own ID.  For instance, if you have two buttons, both of them have spread ID.  These below links would be useful.

Comment: 1) https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: 2) https://www.dofactory.com/html/button/id

Comment: AVOID w3schools. For starters, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: Why should I avoid w3? It's pretty useful

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Ensure the class name or ID are set to your elements:

```html
<div class="my-div-class" id="my-div-id"></div>
```

And then in your stylesheet, you can access these using 'selectors'. Classes are selected with a preceding `.`, and IDs with a preceding `#`:

```css
.my-div-class {
  /* Some styles... */
}

#my-div-id {
  /* Some styles... */
}
```

You can see all CSS selectors here from W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php

Or here from MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors